# I can't access my phone after a factory reset, because the Gboard doesn't work!

Tags: recovery-mode, google

After doing a factory reset on my Huawei p9 lite because it was missing a lot of features like the calculator, alarm, notes and even Bluetooth. After it asks me to log in my linked google account, I can't type my email because the Gboard doesn't work, it shows up the microphone and it doesn't even want to listen to my voice!

Comment: How got the device so messed up? Did you managed to get root access and changed the installed system apps?

Comment: I rooted it for 2 years just fine till It got soft-bricked or something similar, but I got it fixed at an official Huawei store where I live for 50$ but I somehow didn't even notice the calc and apps missing until it was too late, I decided to do a factory reset and thought it would fix it, but the keyboard doesn't work, I'm lost on what to do @Robert

Comment: flash stock ROM. make sure flashing process does not include accidentially re-locking bootloader, keep bootloader unlocked

Comment: How can I flash a ROM if I don't have access to any menus or anything it's only the google verification thing and that's it @alecxs Also in FASTBOOT mode it says "Phone Unlocked" and "FRP LOCK" don't know if this is useful or not, but just in case.

Comment: I don't know if this is so complicated or am I just dumb, but I've been trying stuff for what seems like ages, and I can't figure it out, is there a certain guide I should be following? @alecxs

Comment: You can try a USB-OTG cable and connect a USB keybaord.

Comment: it seems there is official [TWRP](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=4152001) available for your device (since ~1 week) please try this one instead

Answer (score 1):

install latest [platform-tools](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads)
download [service ROM](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3688120) according to your phone model
connect usb-cable and enter [fastboot mode](https://www.hardreset.info/devices/huawei/huawei-l31-p9-lite/fastboot-mode) (Vol Dn + Power)
install [usb-drivers](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb)
flash the common partitions only

```
fastboot flash boot boot.img
fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
fastboot flash system system.img
fastboot flash cust cust.img
fastboot flash vendor vendor.img
fastboot flash product product.img
fastboot flash version version.img
fastboot format:ext4 cache
fastboot format:ext4 userdata
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112439/discussion-on-answer-by-alecxs-i-cant-access-my-phone-after-a-factory-reset-be).