# flash tool for Huawei HiSilicon hi6250 Kirin 650 (locked)

Tags: fastboot, huawei, gboard

Unable to access my phone after a factory reset, because the Gboard doesn't work and I can't type my email and such, I've tried every possible solution I could find to no avail is there a flash tool for Huawei HiSilicon hi6250 Kirin 650 I could use?

some info :
fastboot mode **says** "Phone Unlocked"                                                 and
"FRP LOCK" and
*fastboot boot twrp.img* **says** *FAILED (remote: Command not allowed)* and
**Device model is VNS-L31** (Huawei p9 Lite)

past post with some information
[I can't access my phone after a factory reset, because the Gboard doesn't work!](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/229013/i-cant-access-my-phone-after-a-factory-reset-because-the-gboard-doesnt-work)

Comment: at least, there exist special nocheck fastboot for [Kirin 960](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3915693) and [Kirin 620](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3175387) (have to dig more on this)

Comment: join telegram group @hi6250_5 ask for flash tool. i don't have telegram, please keep us up to date

Comment: Ok I messaged him, just waiting for a response back

Comment: pls anybody bring some light in usage of [Huawei-Update-MultiLoader-Tool](https://forum.gsmhosting.com/vbb/11504634-post15.html) HiSilicon Kirin 650 chipset? make it answer (for the bounty)

Comment: @alecxs please join this room. Will post replies there https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112709/flash-tool-for-huawei-hisilicon-hi6250-kirin-650-locked

Answer (score 0):

not a sufficient answer but based on comments the best option so far is flashing via test point method in VCOM_DOWNLOAD mode.

I leave link only here in good faith that xda-developers never takes it offline

https://www.xda-developers.com/huawei-honor-bootloader-unlock-potatonv