# Recover data from bootlooping phone

Tags: adb, fastboot

The phone is bootlooping and I can only get to fastboot mode. It says PHONE Unlocked, but I can't flash TWRP. How can I recover the data?

Comment: What happens when you try to flash TWRP? Show us the the output of your console/cmd. // Also, which phone and Android version are you using? Which TWRP version did you use and from where did you download it?

Comment: @Firelord `C:\ADB>fastboot flash recovery twrp-3.1.1-0-grace.img
target reported max download size of 471859200 bytes
sending 'recovery' (26226 KB)...
OKAY [  0.640s]
writing 'recovery'...
FAILED (remote: Command not allowed)
finished. total time: 0.662s` The phone is a Huawei P8, it has android 6. I downloaded TWRP from the official website.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community I'm trying to recover the data from a bootlooping phone. I can only get it to fastboot but I cannot flash anything.

Comment: try boot twrp or flash recovery2 https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/twrp-3-2-2-unofficial-huawei-p8-gra-l09.3811895

Comment: @alecxs I tried, but got error. `C:\ADB>fastboot flash recovery2 twrp-3.1.1-0-grace.img
target reported max download size of 471859200 bytes
sending 'recovery2' (26226 KB)...
OKAY [  0.611s]
writing 'recovery2'...
FAILED (remote: Command not allowed)
finished. total time: 0.611s`

Comment: try `fastboot boot <file>`

Comment: @alecxs same error

Comment: sounds like your phone is FRP locked. try IDT Image Download Tool or check these comments https://android.stackexchange.com/q/229072